# EF join 2 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with my code.
I tried many things, but nothing work.

Currently, I have my data in 2 tables, with datas in one table, and in the other table, the content.

Now, how to translate this in EF, and only show the CompetitionName column, that has been translated from the Id to the name, hosted in the 2nd table?

I can do the relation in SQL:

```sql
SELECT Rewards.Id, Rewards.CompetitionId, Competitions.CompetitionName
FROM Rewards
INNER JOIN Competitions
ON Rewards.CompetitionId=Competitions.CompetitionId`
```

It returns me the right result.

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
// GET: Rewards
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    if (_context.Rewards == null)
    {
        return Problem("Entity set 'RewardsContext.Rewards'  is null.");
    }

    var query = from reward in _context.Rewards
                join competition in _context.Competitions
                on reward.CompetitionId equals competition.CompetitionId
                select new
                {
                    reward.Id,
                    competition.CompetitionName
                };

    var rewardsWithTranslatedCompetitionNames = query.ToList();

    return View(rewardsWithTranslatedCompetitionNames);
}
```

Model:

```
public class Reward
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Competition")]
    [Required]
    public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "League")]
    public string LeagueId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Game Week")]
    public string GameWeekId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public string CardTypeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Year")]
    public string? YearId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Number")]
    public string? Number { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Comment")]
    public string? Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Competition
{
    public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Competition Name")]
    public string CompetitionName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't do JOINs in an ORM like EF Core, you specify relations. The ORM generates the JOINs when needed automatically. That's the whole point of using ORMs. If you try to load or use `Competition.Rewards` EF itself will generate  a JOIN. The same with `Reward.Competition`

Comment: In this case you can use `_context.Rewards.Select(r=>new {Reward=r, CompetitionName=r.Competition.CompetitionName}).ToList();`. EF will generate the JOIN and SELECT that returns just the data you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried, without success. I'm closed to the end, but to be honest, for this part, I'm lost. I created all tables and relations through EF, and here, I just want to show the name of the id located in another table instead of the id it self

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using lazy loading is NOT the whole point of ORM tools at all. In fact, most ORM tools dont have such functionality, and some may not even prefer to use lazy loading. I myself prefer to perform joins explicitly because it is much more readable and predictable in my opinion.

Comment: @EmreBener I never said it is or wrote anything remotely like that at all. I said it's to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. The library that deals with tables and rows is ADO.NET.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you said specifying relations for joins to be auto-generated is the whole point of using ORMs.

Comment: Yes, which says nothing about lazy loading at all. JOINs are used for *eager* loading anyway

Comment: how then, are you supposed to load data without actually writing linq queries with join? isn't this what you imply by "specifying relations"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: You link to the actual answer. If you have a `Blog.Posts`, EF or NHibernate or (fill your ORM here) will generate queries that will materialize the objects. They may do that using JOINs or not, depending on the query strategy. They'll try to hide the details from the developer up to a point. The relational and object models are so different that at some point, things start to break down. That's why ORMs are called a leaky abstraction. Using LINQ to emulate SQL is even leakier though - LINQ is the ORM's query language, not embedded SQL

Comment: @EmreBener don't confuse LINQ as a query language with the ORMs, that may or may not use LINQ

Comment: Since the question was about EF and LINQ, and OP is using a database, I had the impression that you were talking about specifying navigational properties and then using "Include" and "ThenInclude" methods of LINQ to perform joins (what else could you have meant by "specifying relations"?). Furthermore, I thought you said using those methods to load data is the whole point of using ORM tools, to which I reacted negatively (I suppose I misunderstood you, though I still don't know what you really was trying to say). What you just said does not answer what I asked.

Comment: I suppose my intervention was unencessary as you did write a query up there without such method. My apologies, let's avoid extended discussions in comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that worked:

```
            List<Reward> model = new List<Reward>();
        var query = (from reward in _context.Rewards
                     join competition in _context.Competitions
                     on reward.CompetitionId equals competition.CompetitionId
                     join league in _context.Leagues
                     on reward.LeagueId equals league.LeagueId
                     join gw in _context.GameWeeks
                     on reward.GameWeekId equals gw.GameWeekId
                     select new
                     {
                         compName = competition.CompetitionName,
                         leagueName = league.LeagueName,
                         gwName = gw.GameWeekName
                     }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            model.Add(new Reward()
            {
                CompetitionId = item.compName,
                LeagueId = item.leagueName,
                GameWeekId = item.gwName
            });
        }

        return View(model);
```

Comment: Do `select new Reward` and remove `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you are working with an existing database and want to perform a join between two tables using Entity Framework Core in a **database-first** approach, you can follow these steps:

**Generate Models from Database:**
First, you will need to generate the entity models based on your existing database schema. You can use **Scaffold-DbContext** method in package manager console inside Visual Studio to create model classes based on your existing database.
So, in Package Manger Console (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console), run the following command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "YourConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context YourDbContext
```

**Define Model Classes in your DbContext:**
Once you have the models generated, you can define your DbContext properties in your context file like so:

```
public partial class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Reward> Rewards { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Competition> Competitions { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

**Performing Join Query:**
Now you are ready to perform the join query using LINQ. It might look like this:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

    public YourController(YourDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = from reward in _dbContext.Rewards
                    join competition in _dbContext.Competitions
                    on reward.CompetitionId equals competition.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        reward.Id,
                        competition.CompetitionName
                    };

        var rewardsWithTranslatedCompetitionNames = query.ToList();

        return View(rewardsWithTranslatedCompetitionNames);
    }
}
```

I did not know how much of the steps you have already done as the question was relatively short, so I tried to give you a full overview of the things you need to have in place, and not just the LINQ query. Let me know if you ahve any questions or if something doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only the query is missed, because at this time, on the view, I only have number instead of names. I implemented your feedback, but I have an error on the join:

The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

I use nvarchar instead of int, can it be the issue?

Comment: I changed from string to int, new error on the webpage:
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FanLiveRugby.Models.Reward]'.

Comment: @FlorentAPPOINTAIRE can you show your query?

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the initial post with my model and my controller.

Comment: Hi,@ Florent APPOINTAIRE，please try select new Reward{  ......}  in your linq expression

Comment: hey, thanks for updating the question to include code. the error is actually pretty self-explanatory. your model is expecting a model of type `IEnumerable<Reward>`, but you are sending it a list instead. you can convert a list to enumerable with LINQ method "AsEnumerable". try `return View(rewardsWithTranslatedCompetitionNames.AsEnumerable() );`. Alternatively, you can update your view model to expect a list.

Comment: Finally, based on your feedbacks, I'm able to do what I wanted to do, thanks